# Memory fault in memcpy call

Tags: c, linux, gcc, uclibc

Im facing with a "memory fault" when calling to:

```
extern void *memcpy (void *__restrict __dest,
         __const void *__restrict __src, size_t __n)
 __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));
```

This is the piece of code:

```
    fprintf(stderr, "sysconfig line 440 \n");
fprintf(stderr, "Value size: %d ; Pointer mymsg: %p ; Pointer value: %p ; mymsg->mtext: %s ; value: %s ; size: %d ;   \n", strlen(value), mymsg, value, mymsg->mtext, value, size);
memcpy(mymsg->mtext, value, size);
fprintf(stderr, "sysconfig line 442 \n");
```

mymsg is a pointer to struct:

```
MSG_T *mymsg;
```

MSG_T:

```
typedef struct msgInfo {
int cmd;
int arg1;
int arg2;
char    mtext[MAX_SEND_SIZE];
} MSG_T;
```

`MAX_SEND_SIZE = 4096`, value is a (void *)char *string containing "" (\0 or empty chain) and size = 4096, so i dont understand why im getting a memory fault. Im checking there is not memory overlapping.
This is the output of execution:

```
sysconfig line 440 
Value size: 0 ; Pointer mymsg: 0x7fd49ac4 ; Pointer value: 0x7fd4ab4c ; mymsg->mtext:      ; value:  ; size: 4096 ;   
Memory fault
```

I have not found What kind of condition here can result in segmentation since all memory has been well allocated, value is a empty string and there is no memory overlapping.

I only get memory fault sometimes (it seems randomly) and other times the process follow executing and exit with no errors.

Comment: How is memory object pointed by `mymsg` allocated?

Comment: Hi @ouah mymsg = &qbuf.msg; While qbuf is not inizialized and is of struct mymsgbuf type; mymsgbuf is `struct mymsgbuf {
        long mtype;   
        long request;   
 MSG_T msg;
};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> memcpy(mymsg->mtext, value, size);

`value` is a string of length `0` and you are trying to copy `4096` bytes from this string. You are therefore accessing `4095` unallocated bytes which means you are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: I thought memcpy only copy until size value or end of string (\0) but if memcpy copy a binary image and is not related with strings functions why its declared in string.h header?

Comment: @user2119381  The standard location of `memcpy()` floated around for a number of years, finally settling in `string.h`.  I recall 'mem.h' and 'memory.h'.  Pose the question on SO is you like.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that value is a (void *)char *string containing "". but size argument for memcpy is 4096, that is the probelm.